# what happens on multiple purchase - Non-Renewal subscription in-app purchase

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, in-app-purchase

I am implementing a sample which includes the in-app purchase feature. The subscription is of non-renewal type.

In case of auto-renewal subscription, if the user has made a purchase, and within the validity period if the user retries to make the purchase, the iTunes shows the alert that

> You are already subscribed to the purchase

and won't proceed further. The user can restore his subscription using the app restore feature.

But in case of non-renewal subscription type, if a user has made a purchase, and within the validity period if the user retries to make the purchase, the iTunes shows a confirmation alert that

> You have already purchased the subscription, to renew or extend the
>   subscription press buy or press cancel

and if the user presses buy it proceeds further.

So, my doubt is what exactly happens in the later case (non-renewal repeated subscription).

Is the user again charged?

What happens with the user's subscription validity?

Can it be handled and controlled inside the code by me?

In case yes, any idea to proceed with would be highly appreciated and will be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Apple, there is no "within the validity period" for non-renewing subscriptions. The duration of the period, fortunately or unfortunately, is left up to the developer.

Yes, when the user buys a non-renewing subscription a second (or third, etc) time, the are charged again.

Subscription validity is up to the developer.

It seems common for developers to use their own server to track the expiry period of a non-renewing subscription. For example, this helps with the "restore" feature required by Apple.

Answer (score 0):

You can alter the subscription start date from the day of repurchase of the APP. This will enable extended validity.

This validity extension mechanism also serves when the user realizes his subscription is about to expire and renews it before hand rather than letting the subscription end.

From the development perspective, logging the first subscribed time along with the current sub and expire time would serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i am altering the subscription start date obviously, and i am getting this from the transaction. According to this subscription start date i am altering the expiry date as well.

The concern here is to avoid the user from getting charged again in any case if he has already subscribed. And, for that i am using iCloud to support restore functionality in user's multiple devices.