# Is it possible to un-Subscribe the Non-Renewing Subscription?

Tags: ios7, in-app-purchase

I am implementing the **Non-Renewable subscription** in my application.

When user try to subscribe first time then its successfully done. When its again before validity is over then it says

[image]

Is there anyway that we can un-subscribe the **Non-Renewable subscription**?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832949/what-happens-on-multiple-purchase-non-renewal-subscription-in-app-purchase

Comment: @Rushabh I have to un-subscribe product.

Comment: Why do you have to unsubscribe the product? The message is to advise the user that they have previously purchased the subscription, and to confirm that they wish to renew / extend. The subscription lengths are managed by you, and has nothing to do with the AppStore.

Comment: Thanks MrNeilM : As double check in-app guideline and get clear about it. Thanks for your help.