# Non-Renewal subscription in-app purchase - multiple purchase on the same item possible?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I'm little perplexed.

Let's say my app has two subscription options. One is "$0.99 / 1 year" another one is "$2.99 / Forever"

What really happens if a user buys $0.99 option twice?

I have searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21832949/what-happens-on-multiple-purchase-non-renewal-subscription-in-app-purchase) stackoverflow article that has an accepted answer saying "Yes, when the user buys a non-renewing subscription a second (or third, etc) time, the are charged again."

But [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html) says "If the user attempts to purchase a product that’s already been purchased, rather than using your app’s restoration interface, the App Store creates a regular transaction instead of a restore transaction. The user isn’t charged again for the product."

Which one is correct?

I tested with some real app from app store, buying them twice and it seems that they don't charge me twice.

So, may I trust the above Apple doc %100?

If so, I will have another question.

Let's say a user had bought 1 year option and a year passed so it has expired. The user buy 1 year option again, however, App Store do not charge the user again since it's been bought before? Then how can I sell the same item again? (in case non-renewal subscription)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three different types of in-app purchase available:

1. Non-consumable purchases
2. Consumable purchases
3. Subscriptions

And there are two types of subscriptions:

1. Auto renewing subscriptions
2. Non-renewing subscriptions.

Non-consumable items can only be purchased once. The user has the ability to restore this purchase and an attempt to purchase it a second time will result be treated like restoration; the user won't be charge a second time.

Your "$2.99 forever" product falls under this category, since a subscription would be for a limited time.  Once the user has purchased this product then you should prevent them from purchasing the subscription products by disabling them in your store interface.

For your "$0.99/year" option you can use auto-renewing or non-renewing subscriptions.

If you use auto-renewing subscriptions then Apple will take care of "purchasing" the product again when the expiration date is reached and if the user attempts to purchase a second time while they already have a subscription active a payment won't be processed.

If you use non-renewing subscription then it is your responsibility to handle subscription expiration and allowing the user to restore their active subscriptions on another device.  In this case you could take a couple of approaches:

- If the user has an active subscription don't allow them to purchase any more subscriptions by disabling the purchase option in your store interface in your app
- Allow them to purchase a second (or third etc) time and extend the expiration date accordingly.  e.g. If they purchase today, the subscription would expire in August 2017.  If they purchase a new subscription before the old one expires, extend the date so it now expires in August 2018.

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helped me!

Comment: I'm just testing this flow out, attempting to use option 3.2 (non-renewing) and handling expiry on my backend. When I try to purchase again The App-Store shows a dialog saying the user already bought the item so tries to restore it, not allowing to purchase again. Is that what's supposed to happen?

Comment: Have you correctly completed the original purchase transaction?  You shouldn't get that dialog unless the original transaction is still pending.

Answer (score 1):

Each in-app purchase is marked in iTunesConnect as either Consumable or Non-Consumable. The user can re-purchase "consumable" items over and over (could be buying more gold in a game, etc.) Non-consumable is purchased just once (like, permanently unlocking content).

You can find the type on iTunesConnect | the app name | Features | In-App Purchases

Comment: so non-renewal subscription is also a consumable product since it can be bought over and over??